# How can raven-php be used with log4php to log to sentry

Tags: php, sentry, log4php

I have an existing `PHP` project using `log4php`, and I'm looking for some sort of `LoggerAppenderSentry` as suggested [in this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4PHP-214), to log messages to [sentry](https://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using the `log4php` `logger` object.

Unfortunately, [the existing appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders.html) do not seem to support sentry yet.

Alternatively, if no existing solutions exist in the wild, I would love some guidelines / tutorial / blog entry as to how to write a custom appender for `log4php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of mentioned issue, [Valdemar Jordan](https://github.com/vbjordan), has been so kind to publish his appender in a [fork of log4php on github](https://github.com/vbjordan/logging-log4php).

I confirmed this solution to work properly, for more info, see [the appender source](https://github.com/vbjordan/logging-log4php/blob/8ccd79549bba6c4e0eb8b2bd58607833e817c979/src/main/php/appenders/LoggerAppenderSentry.php) and [my pull request](https://github.com/vbjordan/logging-log4php/pull/1) for more usage details.